# Lock an application for multi users

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have developed an application to be deployed on server using java and Struts2.It makes changes to files,so I want to limit the access to one user at a time to avoid inconsistency in data.How can I do that?Please help

Comment: That's a weird requirement, are you sure?  why not just synchronize the file modification code?

Answer (score 0):

How about writing a class that provides method to read/write those files. And this class exposing synchronized read/write functions.

e.g

```
public class FileManager {
  HashMap<String, File> _fileHandleMap;

  public synchronized void doWrite(String fileHandle, String bufferToWrite) {
     .....
  }

  public synchronized String doRead(String fileHandle) {
  }

}
```

Idea is to encapsulate file reading/writing operations in one class and synchronize the access of read/write operations of that class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the file system to create a "lock" file for the file that is being edited.  If someone has that file open in your application - the lock file is next to it.  Once the user is done editing that file, the lock file disappears and the other user is able to open the file.

Answer (score 0):

In same application but for multiple threads we can `synchronize` the access. But for multiple application on the same file (e.g. multiple instance of the same application in java) we can do this:

```
 RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile( "scatterAndGather.txt", "rw" );
 FileChannel fc = raf.getChannel();
 fileLock=fc.lock(0, fc.size(), false);
```

This will be across the application and is managed by OS.